# How to implement google place picker using Google's new Place SDK 1.0 latest

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How to implement Google map place picker in android studio using google new place sdk library

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot use **PlacePicker** anymore starting 29 july 2019 .

> Notice: The Place Picker (Android, iOS) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date.

You should build you own UI based on the new **Google places SDK**

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) you can learn more about it

Comment: In addition to this, Google is conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, if you are interested, kindly add your answer in the form mentioned in this issue (Android) issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) issuetracker.google.com/128304760.

Comment: @rafon Add my comment to these 2 issue tracker. Don't think we could have place picker back though ...